# Django: Creating model instances with a random integer field value that average up to a specified number

Tags: database, django, django-models, statistics

I have a model like so:

```
class RunnerStat(models.Model):
    id_card= models.CharField(max_length=32)
    miles = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    last_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to create several `RunnerStat` instances with random `miles` values that average up to a specific number.

I know this might involve some statistics (distribution, etc.). Does anyone have any pointers? Or done something similar and could share some code?

**Example**: Create 100 `RunnerStat` objects with random `miles` values that average out to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the average has to be around the the given number but not exactly it you can use the `random.gauss(mu, sigma)` from the random module. This will create a more natural random set of of values that have a mean (average) around the given value for `mu` with a standard deviation of `sigma`. The more runners you create the closer the mean will get to the desired value.

```
import random

avg = 10
stddev = 5
n = random.gauss(avg,stddev)
for r in range(100):
  r = RunnerStat(miles=avg+n)
  r.save()
```

If you need the average to be the exact number then you could always create a runner (or more reasonably a few runners) that counter balance what ever your current difference from the mean is.

Comment: I am going to try that tomorrow.

Comment: Ah sorry. Yes! Thanks for the follow up and apologize for the delay on selecting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well for something to average to a specific number, they need to add up to a specific number. For instance, if you want 100 items to average to 10, the 100 items need to add up to 1000 since 1000/100 = 10.

One way to do this, which isn't completely random is to generate a random number, then both subtract and add that to your average, generating two RunnerStat items.

So you do something like this (note this is from my head and untested):

```
import random

avg = 10

n = random.randint(0,5)

r1 = RunnerStat(miles=avg-n)
r2 = RunnerStat(miles=avg+n)

r1.save()
r2.save()
```

Of course fill in the other fields too. I just put the miles in the RunnerStats. The downside is that your RunnerStats must be an even number. You could write it to pass in a number and if it is odd the last one must be exactly the number you want the average to be.